# How to drop a subgraph in Tinkerpop (OrientDB) gremlin query?

Tags: java, graph, orientdb, gremlin, tinkerpop

Requirement is to drop this subgraph if I have `runId` and `appId`. Application can have multiple such appId and thus should be deleted only if no `appId` is attached to it.

I have tried the below query to drop the subgraph, but only `IO` and `appRun` gets dropped. The `iRecord` & `oRecord` don't get dropped. Is this because I loose the gremlin pointer? So question is how to delete the `iRecord` and `oRecord`.

I was planning to delete the `appId` in second traversal call. So can I check if the `appId` has no more connected `runId` and drop `appId` in the same traversal.

```
db.getTraversal()
                .V().has("aRun", "runId", runId).as("aRun")
                .outE("hasIO")
                .inV().hasLabel("io").as("io")
                .sideEffect(outE("output").inV().has("oRecord").drop())
                .sideEffect(inE("input").outV().has("iRecord").drop())
                .sideEffect(select("aRun").drop())
                .sideEffect(select("io").drop())
                .iterate();
```

I also tried version of answer provided here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51547985/gremlin-drop-multiple-vertices)

```
db.getTraversal().
  V().has("aRun", "runId", runId)
  emit().
  repeat(out()).
  fold().
  unfold().
  drop()
```

But this will delete the `oRecord`, `aRun` and `io` but not the `iRecord`. And question of how to drop `appId` remains.

Thanks

[image: Sample Subgraph]

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
 <artifactId>orientdb-gremlin</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: is "oRecord" and "iRecord" are labels or properties? if labels I think your first query doesn't drop them because you are using `has` instead of `hasLabel`

Comment: thanks a lot! yes! it was as easy that.

Answer (score 3):

I used this query:

```
db.getTraversal()
 .V().has("app", "appId", appId).as("app")
 .outE("hasRun")
 .inV().has("aRun", "runId", runId).as("aRun")
 .outE("hasIO")
 .inV().hasLabel("io").as("io")
 .sideEffect(outE("output").inV().hasLabel("oRecord").drop())
 .sideEffect(inE("input").outV().hasLabel("iRecord").drop())
 .sideEffect(select("app").filter(outE("hasRun").count().is(1)).drop())
 .sideEffect(select("aRun").drop())
 .sideEffect(select("io").drop())
 .iterate();
```

Thanks!